# Why is it easy to see $\Phi_{mn}$ is not orthogonal?

Tags: orthogonality

Let:
$$\Phi_{mn}=g(x-mD)e^{-inWx}$$
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt D}P(\frac{2x}{D}h(x))$$
$$P(x)=\begin{cases}
    1       & \quad -1<x\leq 1\\
    0  & \quad \text{else}\\
  \end{cases}$$
were $D=1,W=2\pi$ and 
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
    1       & \quad 0<x\\
    0  & \quad \text{else}\\
  \end{cases}$$
Why is it easy to see $\Phi_{mn}$ is not orthogonal?

It is supposed to be a quick and visible without a proof answer in a multiple choice test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that $g(x)=1$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $0$ outside this interval.

Thus $g(x-m)=1$ on $(m,m+1/2)$ and $0$ outside this interval.

The basis is not orthogonal because - in particular - dot products (in the hermitian sense)

$\langle \Phi_{m,n},  \Phi_{m,n+1} \rangle$ (with the same $m$) are non zero : they are equal to

$$\ \int_{m}^{m+1/2} e^{2i\pi n x}e^{-2i\pi (n+1)x}dx=\int_{m}^{m+1/2} e^{-2i\pi x}dx=\dfrac{i}{\pi}\neq 0$$

**Remark**: one can be fooled by the fact that many other dot products are zero. In particular, if $m \neq m'$, all dot products $\langle \Phi_{m,n},  \Phi_{m',n'} \rangle$ are zero (no common support between $[m,m+1/2]$ and $[m',m'+1/2]$).